# Use custom domain with Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

I have a Google account which I currently use to handle my emails and calendar. Regarding emails, I want to switch to my own domain, but continue using Google Inbox/Gmail. This works perfectly fine regarding emails, but I have problems with the calendar. When someone sends me an appointment to my Gmail address, I can simply accept it, the sender gets a notification, and the appointment appears on my calendar. But when I receive an appointment with my custom domain, I can only accept it when I am not logged in to Google, and there is no way to get them to appear in my calendar.

Any ideas on this?

**UPDATE Dec 2nd**

Alright, it seems that I wasn't precise enough. I have a Google Account which I use for every Google service, e.g. Google Calendar and Google Inbox, among others. Sometimes I use Gmail as well. I also have a custom domain including an email address. The emails are forwarded to my Gmail address. Sending from the custom domain is configured in Gmail as well (and also works in Google Inbox). The email address from my custom domain is also added as a secondary address to my Google account.

If someone sends an event, and I click *Yes* (meaning "accept event"), it says:

> Google calendar invitations can't be forwarded by email. This event belongs to my@customdomain.com, and you are logged in as myname@gmail.com.

If I am not logged in to Google (e.g. if I open the link in another browser, the event gets confirmed to the inviting person as it should. But it doesn't appear in my Google calendar.

Comment: "I can only accept it when I am not logged in to Google" - how so? What happens when you try?

Comment: It sounds like you're using regular Gmail as well as email for Google Apps. Is that correct? It also sounds like you're forwarding your Apps Email to your Gmail account to keep things simpler. And then, when you receive an invitation to your Apps Email address, if you follow the link from the invite,  it tries to add the event to your "normal" calendar, but can't, because that's not the address that was invited. Am I close?

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Accepting the invitation and then copying it to your (Gmail account's) Calendar requires two steps. First, open the invitation email in your Gmail or Google inbox.

1. Accept the invitation by clicking "Yes" in the invitation email's body. It may open a new tab.
2. Add the event to your Gmail Calendar by clicking "Add to calendar >>" in the top portion of the invitation email. (Alternatively, you can download the attached .ics event file and then upload it to Calendar by [following these instructions](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37118?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop). This is a good work around if the event email is not forwarded to your Gmail inbox.)

I don't know about the "This event belongs to my@customdomain.com, and you are logged in as myname@gmail.com" error. Maybe it's been resolved?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/146645)

Answer (score -1):

since you have invite email forwarded to your gmail account, you can:

1. Agree wo visit meeting, it should open new tab with custom domain email and confirm it from there
2. Find an attachment with .ics extension, you can import it from your calendar app (works for mac native calendar app nicely).

In that way, you have an invite on custom domain, which is present in your google calendar, which requires a bit of manual work through (for me its just drag .ispcs from Mail app to Calendar app, but still)